# Not getting appropriate parent id in child process using fork()

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am trying to get the parent id in the child process using `fork()`. However, I don't get the proper parent id. Sometime I do and sometime I don't. My `printf` prints 1 for the parent id. Here is my code snippet. Can anyone explain the reason.

```
for(i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++){      
    if((pid = fork()) == 0){
        printf("Parent id is %u\n", getppid()) ;            
        break ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The process with the id of `1` is the *init* process. Output from `top -p 1` (on my Ubuntu machine):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND             
    1 root      20   0 24732 2704 1376 S    0  0.0   0:00.93 init
```

If a process is orphaned the [*init*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) process adopts the [orphaned process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process), and `getppid()` will return `1` in the orphaned process. In your case, the parent process must be exiting, on occasion, before the child process calls `getppid()`.